Peak current-mode controller
I am studying a peak current-mode controller, and here is the schematic without slope compensation:

Before introducing RSENSE to the design, I understood that if feedback voltage increases, it is compared with a constant VREF to determine to do what with switches. According to the information from the site, the switches are reset when Ri · iL = VEA, indicating that iL can't exceed IEA.

I am encountering difficulties in understanding:

In many designs, RSENSE is selected in a way that iL never reaches IEA. For instance, when I simulate the circuit using LTspice and choose a smaller value for RSENSE, it always operates without issues. However, problems arise when I opt for a larger resistor value, leading to current limiting through the inductor. I am confused about what actually triggers the switches to turn ON/OFF if IEA is picked to be very high. What is going to limit iL then?



The schematic (figure 1) suggests that the switches are reset when Ri · iL > VEA. However, I am puzzled by datasheets such as the one for the LT3890, which consistently mention a fixed sensing voltage, in this case, 50 mV. I am uncertain about the role of this fixed sensing voltage in the comparator. My understanding is limited to the idea that if the sensed voltage exceeds 50 mV, the switches turn off, but I am unsure how this concept aligns with the schematic above.



Yes.  Shunt resistance is a design parameter.

Given that EA is a real op-amp with bounded output voltage (saturation limits), we can select it, and the current sense (resistor, sense amp, offset, and comparator) such that peak current only up to some given design limit can be delivered.
Since the switches and inductor will be selected for a given current range, this allows us to fully bound one aspect of converter operation, greatly improving reliability in the face of uncertain input or output conditions (e.g. output overload or short circuit).
Varying the resistor arbitrarily, is simply varying part of that design limit.  So you are making your design higher or lower powered, but independently of other parameter changes -- which as you have seen, doesn't make a whole lot of sense, or seem to accomplish much at a fixed operating point.  But, even at a fixed operating point, inverter gain and therefore EA compensation is changing, so you can eventually reach a point where gross behavior changes (i.e. instability).

All instances use the term "maximum current sense".

That is, the threshold is variable internally, up to a maximum of this.  This is equivalent to saying: the EA output is 0-50mV, in terms of current sense amp input voltage.

@ Tim Williams:
I want to confirm my understanding. Are you suggesting that even if I select RSENSE in a manner that allows the inductor current to reach 50A, the compensation of EA will change, potentially falling below Ri * iL, thereby resetting the switches? Is that correct?

Compensation is not a voltage, it is a condition of the dynamical system. But if you like, an unstable system will alternate above and below that threshold.  Depending on values, we might not call it "current mode control" anymore, but hysteretic perhaps. What significance is 50A here?

I chose 50A as an example to emphasize that it can be selected quite high, leading to a potential increase in iEA and requiring a significant rise in iL to reach the point of turning off the switches.

However, the concept remains unclear to me, and I find the entire idea confusing. Are there any articles you could recommend for further reading on this topic? Perhaps ones that provide a real design example along with explanations of the waveforms? Although I conducted simulations for LT8390, they did not aid in my understanding of these controller loops. The only insight I gained was that the switches turn off when the voltage across the sensing resistor reaches 50mV.

If you mean what happens when the current setpoint step-changes (whether or not the EA might actually produce such a signal), the latch simply stays on until current rises to that threshold; this can take multiple clock cycles and that's just fine. Current remains bounded below setpoint, no matter how long it takes.

This current setpoint is a big issue for me! I can even adjust it to 100 A (a really big one) by selecting a small sensing resistor, and the simulation runs okay!
